# EMACS Warning (package): Unnecessary call to ‘package-initialize’ in init file

Tags: emacs, package, initialization

I am new to coding started just a month ago. I am preparing ahead for my bootcamp with EMACS. I followed a tutorial and was told to initialize package. The code I used was:

```
(package-initialize)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives ' ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

I keep getting ***warning (package): Unnecessary call to ‘package-initialize’ in init file*** and I don't know what to do next or how to solve it.

Comment: This is something that changed, the tutorial you follow seems to be out of date.  Did you follow the implicit advice of the warning? That is: What happens if you don't call `package-initialize` in your init file?

Comment: @TomRegner thanks that worked. I guess I have to look for a new tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

According to the emacs changelog [1](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-27.2/etc/NEWS#L204-L214), you can get rid of the call to `package-initialize` if you use emacs >= 27:

> Installed packages are now activated *before* loading the init file.
> As a result of this change, it is no longer necessary to call
> 'package-initialize' in your init file.

Also,

> if you want to ensure that your init file is still compatible with earlier versions of Emacs, change it to:

```lisp
(when (< emacs-major-version 27)
  (package-initialize))
```